# jQuery validator issue on Zend framework checkbox

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-validate

I have validation issue when I use ZF checkbox element.

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('iagree', array('uncheckedValue'=>null,'checkedValue'=>'Y','disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true, 'class'=>'required agreetc' ));
$element->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addErrorMessage('You must agree Privacy policy & Terms of use');
$this->addElement($element);
```

Above code outputs :

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="iagree">
<input type="checkbox" class="required agreetc" value="Y" id="iagree" name="iagree">
```

This is my jQuery validator.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.validator.addMethod("agreetc", function(value, element) {
    return $('#iagree').is(':checked');
}, "You must agree Privacy Policy & Terms of Use.");
    $("#register").validate({ignore: ":hidden"});

  });
</script>
```

all other fields are highlighting except check box. I have tried ignore but it is not working

Other solution I tried. I made ZF code so that it will not output hidden field, but the server side check will not work that time.

Answer (score 2):

use the below code

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.validator.addMethod("agreetc", function(value, element) {
    return $('#iagree').not(':hidden').is(':checked');
}, "You must agree Privacy Policy & Terms of Use.");
    $("#register").validate({ignore: ":hidden"});

  });
</script>
```

Comment: excellent work!!! How did you find this out, looks like a zend checkbox is made up or a hidden element

Comment: I had the same problem then i figured out the hidden element.. then it was simple.. you know!! If you found that this is the answer then would you mind checking this as your answer.. thanks